# Rename Arduino nano 33 BLE from characteristics

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-c++

I need to develop a small batch of items with the Arduino Nano BLE 33 with the ArduinoBLE library. Does anybody know the best way to name the things in a batch?

I tried to set up a BLE characteristic with no success:

```
void changeNameCharWritten(BLEDevice central, BLECharacteristic characteristic) 
{
    BLE.setLocalName(changeNameChar.value);
    BLE.setDeviceName(changeNameChar.value);
}
```

The argument is static.

Is there any other way to do it or do I need to write a specific firmware for each device?

Comment: Suggest you consider conditional build or make settings which enable different statics for different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinoble/ble.setlocalname/) does not suggest that changing the name is not possible.

Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/blob/8ca541559676bc88dce841a889d80ba557fb0399/src/local/BLELocalDevice.cpp#L349) of `BLELocalDevice::advertise()` I would assume that you need to call `BLE.advertise()` to update the name after you did set it.

To extend your example:

```
void changeNameCharWritten(BLEDevice central, BLECharacteristic characteristic) 
{
    BLE.setLocalName(changeNameChar.value);
    BLE.setDeviceName(changeNameChar.value);
    // BLE.stopAdvertise() might be needed before
    BLE.advertise()
}
```

Comment: changeNameChar.value needs to be const char

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? `setLocalName` want a pointer to a const char, but you can simply pass a different pointer